# Manage new product and old product price in e-commerce sites

Tags: php, product, price

I am working on e-commerce website in PHP (Code-igniter framework). i am facing one challenge.

The Problem detail is

I have product (name: xyz). the quantity of xyz product is 30 and it's each xyz product price is 120. then i buy more quantity (150 quantity) of xyz product at price 100.

1. if I show on website xyz product with price 120 (old price) and
   total stock remaining 180 then user will not buy because price is
   high and user will buy to another website.
2. if I show on website xyz product with price 100 (latest price)
   and total stock remaining 180 then i lost 600 dollars (20 price x 30
   quantity)

What can i do to solve this problem ?

Please provide any suggestion about this problem

Comment: This is business not technical question. You can simply show 120 for the first 30 units then automatically turn to 100. You can make an offer to user for the first 30 units to receive extra gift. In fact, you should have a **profit margin**. As a supplier, your margin can goes up or down a bit. That is business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the issue

1. if I show on website xyz product with price 120 (old price) and
   total stock remaining 180 then user will not buy because price is
   high and user will buy to another website.
2. if I show on website xyz product with price 100 (latest price) and
   total stock remaining 180 then i lost 600 dollars (20 price x 30
   quantity)

the solution is: Production Company is responsible to exchange my remaining inventory with new price

Answer (score 0):

For such purposes, you can use SKU.
In your case, this is worth 1 product but with different price, as the purchase price was different. More details can be written [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit). Good luck!

Comment: i know about SKU. but my need is: which price i show to user ?

Comment: In my opinion, this question refers to the business process of the store, and not to the implementation in the code. Some practices increase prices for all products, even if they were purchased at a lower price.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using mysql do this on your query:

```
GROUP BY concat(ProductID , '-' , Price)
```

This will list your products separated by it's price.